# Return a WCF EF4 Entity as JSON

Tags: wcf, json, entity-framework-4

My service interface is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "HelloJSON/{name}")]
    string HelloJSON(string name);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetEmployees")]
    List<Employee> GetEmployees();
}
```

My implementation is:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string HelloJSON(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello {0} in JSON", name);
    }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        using (DBEntities ctx = new DBEntities())
        {
            List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
            emp = (from e in ctx.Employee select e).ToList();
            return emp;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the first method I get something like "Hello pepe in JSON", that's ok.

When I call the second method and set a breakpoint on line "return emp;" I get the list of the employees(there are 6 records from the database), but in IE I get this:

Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

and testing in Firefox all I get is a blank page with a blank body, no HTML, no data and no errors.

I think WCF can't serialize my default EF4 entities.

EDIT:

My final solution was something(not exactly) like this:

```
static string SerializeJSON<T>(T obj) {
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(obj); }
```

Comment: Try using Chrome or perhaps FireBug in Firefox to debug client-side. For example, if your Employee has a circular reference then JSON serialization will fail. If you can find the error, it would help immensely in solving it.

Comment: Well, all I'm doing is a test and Employee is the only table in that DB, I already checked Firebug and nothing, all seems normal, no errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well I have not used WebInvoke for JSON serialization, so I don't know about how it works, but I use JSON serialization with my WCF services. I use this `return this.JSON(emp)` with a return type of `JsonResult` and it works fine. Good luck.

Comment: I found the error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The type 'xxx' cannot be serialized to JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'. The JSON format does not support references because there is no standardized format for representing references. To enable serialization, disable the IsReference setting on the type or an appropriate parent class of the type.'.

Comment: try this: this works for me
Link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22794494/3120377

Comment: here is solution to return json returntype in Entity framework
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22794494/3120377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF entities cannot be serialized by default you must add code generation to them.

Refer to this article on how to create Serializable entities.

called [Self Tracking entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to enable RIA Services and expose JSON Endpoint, it does everything correctly.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/14/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-json-endpoint-4-5.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-26-Exposing-SOAP-OData-and-JSON-Endpoints-for-RIA-Services