# Entity framework - WCF - return JSON how to do this?

Tags: json, wcf, entity-framework

I have all the POCO entities produced from my database. I created an IXXX interface, a XXX class to define the structure of the table I want to return from my service, and a XXX class to do the query and the return part for the interface.

My question is regarding the elements I need to add to this setup in order to return clean JSON from my web service.

I'm a beginner so all points of view are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: did you try googling for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define XXXDto classes which are having a clean format for your client needs. And then map the domain/endity classes to Dto objects and serialize them using WCF.

Or you can [create WCF OData services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/572417/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusforplusCreatingpl) to expose the service as OData source.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

To return Json data [in EF]:

1. add reference 'System.Runtime.Serialization' to the project
2. write code like below:

`using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

```
public string getValuesJson()
{
     JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     MyDBEntities ctx = new MyDBEntities();

     var myValues = (from m in ctx.TestEntity
                    where (m.id == 22)
                    select m).ToList();

     return js.Serialize(myValues);
}
```

you can also check whether Json string is valid or not at http://jsonlint.com/